# Calendar appointments missing data

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

One of my users is experiencing an issue with certain calendar appointments. After accepting, the body of the appointment is cut off, sometimes mid-sentence, displaying only the first few lines of content. The issue persists when I access the mailbox from another machine, and also in OWA. We are running Exchange Server 2007.

What could cause this?

Comment: Certain appointments? Is there a pattern as to which appointments this occurs with?

Comment: No pattern at all. Some are fine and some do not display all data.

Comment: For only one user? And because it's on OWA it's server-side, not client side?

Comment: Yes, only one user is experiencing this.  It's definitely server-side; I just don't know what it could be.